# Brachistochrone Problem with friction step 29 to 30

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am developing step by step the problem of the brachystochrone with friction described in [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) but I don't understand how to go from step 29 to 30, i.e.,

how reduces this equation

$(1+y'^2)(1+\mu y')+2(y-\mu x)y''=0$

into

$\frac{1+y^{\prime 2}}{(1+\mu y^\prime)^2}=\frac{C}{y-\mu x}$

Comment: The $C$ in (30) disappears if it's alone and you differentiate. Have you tried making it alone and then differentiating everything, see whether you can get to (29) that way?

Comment: use the relation: $y''dy = y'd(y')$ which is a chain rule

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4622262/11127