# Brachistochrone with friction (substitution and partial fractions)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions

This [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) article on the brachistochrone makes the following step in lines (29) and (30):

$$\left( 1 + y \prime ^ 2\right) \left( 1 + \mu y \prime \right) + 2 \left( y - \mu x  \right) y \prime \prime = 0$$
can be reduced to:
$$\frac{1 + y \prime ^ 2}{\left( 1 + \mu y \prime \right)^2} = \frac{C}{y - \mu x}$$

I found the original journal article from 1995 that the article was based off of, and it doesn't show any more work but it says that this can be solved "**through two substitutions and a partial fractions integration**". I'm not sure how to approach this; I'm asking for any ideas and preferably a detailed solution if possible. Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, you're asking how to reduce equation (29) to (30) and not how to actually solve (30)?

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes

Comment: Ok. It is not actually that difficult in principle to verify (29) from (30): one solves for $C$, differentiates with respect to $x$, and then rearrange to show that this is true whenever (29) holds. This is not pleasant algebra, but it is simple enough with a CAS (see the first result [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+D%5B%281%2By%27%5Bx%5D%5E2%29%28y%5Bx%5D-mu+x%29%2F%28+%281%2Bmu+y%27%5Bx%5D%29%5E2%29%2Cx%5D)). But this is of course not the desired direction.

Comment: Derivatives are usually denoted by superscripted primes, which you get in MathJax using `'`, not `\prime`. The latter is an un-superscripted prime.

Comment: You can get rid of $x$ by substituting $f=y-\mu x$. The resulting equation can be brought into the form $f''g(f)=f'h(f)$, which can be integrated, but the integral of $g$ is a horrible sum of logarithms (plus an arctangent that can be written as a complex logarithm), so that's probably not the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3833932/11127